# How do I stop a video at a specific time using Blend/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video, blend

How do I stop a video at a specific time using Blend/WPF in C#?

Example:

When I clicked on a "TreeViewItem" called "MONDAY", the video will start to play. But up to 10sec of that video, I want it to stop. As after 10sec, that video will be showing video of another "TreeViewItem" called "TUESDAY". So what is the coding for it?

**My coding is shown below:**

```
        if (MONDAY.IsSelected == true)
        {
            Video.Source = new Uri(@".\weekday.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
            Video.Play();
            descriptionText.Text = "Monday Blues";

           ****When video play until 10sec, it will auto stop it****
        }

        else if (TUESDAY.IsSelected == true)
        {
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(VideoTime.Value = 10);
            Video.Position = t;
            descriptionText.Text = "Tuesday is here";
        }
```

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) for 10 seconds, when timer elapsed call [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.stop.aspx)